# How to detect when the element visibility changes (not only :visible, but also visibility visible/hidden)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to detect when a element in page changes visibility?

Please read good the question.

**The reference it's not only to `:visible` pseudo selector (that matches `display: none`, but also on `visibility` visible/hidden.**

After some search you could find that there's a plugin that does this job.

Snippet of the code here:

```js
"use strict";
((typeof jQuery === "function") && !((function($, w) {
  $.fn.extend({
    detectVisibilityChange: function(callback) {
      this.checkForVisiblilityChange(callback);
      return this;
    },

    checkForVisiblilityChange: function(callback) {

      if (!(this.length >>> 0))
        return undefined;

      var elem, i = 0;

      while ((elem = this[i++])) {
        var curValue = $(elem).is(":visible");

        (elem.lastVisibility === undefined) && (elem.lastVisibility = curValue);

        (curValue !== elem.lastVisibility) && (

          elem.lastVisibility = curValue,

          (typeof callback === "function") && (
            callback.apply(this, [new jQuery.Event('visibilityChanged'), curValue ? "shown" : "hidden"])
          ),
          (function(elem, curValue, w) {
            w.setTimeout(function() {
              $(elem).trigger('visibilityChanged', [curValue ? "shown" : "hidden"])
            }, 10)
          })(elem, curValue, w)
        )
      }

      (function(that, a, w) {
        w.setTimeout(function() {
          that.checkForVisiblilityChange.apply(that, a);
        }, 10)
      })(this, arguments, w)
    }
  })
})(jQuery, window))) || console.error("detectVisibilityChange plugin requires jQuery")

$("#toggle_visiblity").click(function() {
  var visible = $("#test_hidden").is(":visible")
  $("#test_hidden")[visible ? "hide" : "show"]();
})
$("#test_hidden").detectVisibilityChange(function(e, visibility) {
  console.log("Visibility changes: " + visibility, e)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center>
  <button id="toggle_visiblity" type="button" style="display: block;"> Hide / Show div</button>
  <div id="test_hidden" style="display: none;">EVENT (also when close this)</div>
</center>
```

but it works only for `:visible` pseudo selector (not for `visibility` visible/hidden) and if you try to expand the selection from a single element `$("#test_hidden")` to a class `$(".class")` or each element in page `$("*")` it does not work well.

---

So, in the end, how to detect when a page element changes visibility?

There's a way to modify this to check out also `elem.css("visibility","hidden") == true` and enabling it for all elements `$("*")`, or there's also an other way to have the required result?

Comment: Inline or external styles? Can use mutation observer for inline.

Comment: Might want to look into whether `trackVisibility` would apply to `visibility: hidden`: https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/v2/#dom-intersectionobserver-trackvisibility.

Comment: @morganney
 - *Inline or external styles? Can use mutation observer for inline.* **Each you write**

Comment: @morganney "*Might want to look into whether trackVisibility would apply to visibility: hidden*". **If you know how to use it... and I'm going mad over this. The function proposed it's written in a complicated way. It looks like Aramaic. If anyone knows how to add a test for `elem.css("visibility","hidden") == true` and customizing it for each element of the page would do me a great favor**

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can monitor changes to CSS [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) for inline styles as well as internal or external stylesheets. You can comment-out any section (inline/internal/external) to see it working with that approach exclusively.

Note, this is not supported across all browsers, as there is only limited support for the [`trackVisibility`](https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/v2/#dom-intersectionobserverinit-trackvisibility) option to the [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) constructor. Also, it is more expensive to compute visibility this way (although probably less-so than polling with `window.getComputedStyle`) and Chrome will provide the following warning in the console:

> Visibility is more expensive to compute than the basic intersection; enabling this option may negatively affect your page's performance. Please make sure you *really* need visibility tracking before enabling the 'trackVisibility' option.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>SO Detect CSS visibility changes</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    #div {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="div">I use visibility CSS</div>
    <div>I do not use visibility CSS</div>
    <script type="module">
      const style = document.createElement('style')
      const link = document.createElement('link')
      const div = document.getElementById('div')
      const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        const visibility = window
          .getComputedStyle(mutations[0].target)
          .getPropertyValue('visibility')

        if (visibility === 'hidden') {
          console.log('[MO]: element is hidden')
        }

        if (visibility === 'visible') {
          console.log('[MO]: element is visible')
        }
      })
      const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        const isVisible = entries[0].isVisible

        if (isVisible) {
          console.log('[IO]: element is visible')
        } else {
          console.log('[IO]: element is hidden')
        }
      }, {
        // Supported in Chrome
        trackVisibility: true,
        delay: 100
      })

      // Respond to visibility changes that are handled via inline CSS
      mutationObserver.observe(div, {
        attributes: true,
        attributeFilter: ['style']
      })
      // Respond to visibility changes that are handled via internal/external CSS stylesheets
      intersectionObserver.observe(div)

      // Hide visibility
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Inline styles
        div.style.visibility = 'hidden'


        // Internal Stylesheet
        style.id = 'style'
        style.innerText = `
          #div {
            visibility: hidden;
          }
        `
        document.head.append(style)

        // External Stylesheet
        link.id = 'link'
        link.href = './styles.css'
        link.rel = 'stylesheet'
        //document.head.append(link)

        // Unhide visibility
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.getElementById('style').remove()
          //document.getElementById('link').remove()
          div.style.visibility = 'visible'
        }, 2000)
      }, 1000)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically, this amounts to:

- Use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect inline changes to `visibility`.
- Use [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) with the [`trackVisibility`](https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/v2/#dom-intersectionobserverinit-trackvisibility) option (in supported browsers) for internal and external stylesheets that include `visibility` values for your observed target.

Here's an example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/detect-css-visibility-changes-30phi2).

Comment: Tnx (for the others). But, here we're not talking about if you work with jQuery or not. For me you can also hoe, it makes no difference. So, good answer, but here a "working in each browser" code it's needed. <3

Comment: I'm not really interested in what you need, but rather the question you presented.

Comment: "I'm not really interested in what you need, but rather the question you presented." Tnx for your altruism